# Unity to android Nook not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, nook, nook-tablet

please mind my english its not good :)

i am trying to import android project for nook and try to run in emulator which is nook hd api level 10 and api level 15.

i import the project for android with min api level 10 also try it with api level 15

but when ever it goes to emulator it gives me this error

`03-26 11:59:47.623: E/Unity(980): (Filename: PlatformDependent/AndroidPlayer/Source/UnityEGLConfig.cpp Line: 203)
03-26 11:59:47.623: E/Unity(980): [EGL] Unable to find an configuration matching minimum spec!
03-26 11:59:47.623: E/Unity(980):

03-26 11:59:47.623: E/Unity(980): (Filename: PlatformDependent/AndroidPlayer/Source/ContextGLES.cpp Line: 204)`

i try various options but it didnt work. despratly need this done

Comment: I think that you probably want the [tag:unity3d] tag, not the [tag:unity] one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot. not response from nook developer fourm as well. i find the solution

dont try to run it on emulator . try it on physical device it will work . because emulator is missing with graphics api which stop application to work :)

Cheers